# How to put two children into one cell in a tablelayout in android?

Tags: android, tablelayout

How do you put two children into one cell in  table layout I andorid? Is is even possible,  can't seem to find anything on the internet.

Comment: Can you maybe supply an image of what you're trying to accomplish? And if it's what I think it is, then yes. Especially if doing it programmatically, you can use a layout in place of a TableRow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the two children in a layout. This will cause the cell to have one child that has two children in it.

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just combine the two `View`s into one `LinearLayout` and make that the cell.

So the hierarchy is like this:

```
- table
  - row
    - view
    - view
    - layout
      - child view
      - child view
    - view
  - row
  ...
```

Then both children will appear as one cell (in my example above, the 3rd of 4 cells).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can wrap them in a `LinearLayout`